# How to apply texture to an object face avoiding triangular mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing

I am facing a problem, 
as I apply a texture to the detached face of a cube.

Instead of being spread over the face, 
it is repeated in mesh triangles & is distorted.

[image: here you can see the render of the face]

Could you suggest a way to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to map the texture: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Select faces, hit U, Unwrap. Google search UV unwrapping, this is an important topic that you should learn and won't be explained in full here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,